# Text not setting to mutable string

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add text to a variable and use that in the dialog but it wont put anything in. 
Here is my code:

```
var dex = ""
firestoreInstance.collection("test").whereEqualTo("module", listMod[spinnerMod.selectedItemPosition].ID).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
     if (!task.result.isEmpty) for (document in task.result) {
          dex += "Success"
     } else {
          dex += "Fail"
     }
}
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setMessage(dex).setTitle(dex).show()
```

and this is the output:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase `Task`s execute asynchronously. What's happening is that you fire off your query and immediately put up an `AlertDialog` while `dex` is still an empty string. Then, when the query completes, it changes `dex`'s value, but it's never read again.

You could instead show the dialog when the task completes:

```
firestoreInstance.collection("test").whereEqualTo("module", listMod[spinnerMod.selectedItemPosition].ID).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
     var dex = ""
     if (!task.result.isEmpty) for (document in task.result) {
          dex += "Success"
     } else {
          dex += "Fail"
     }
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(dex).setTitle(dex).show()
}
```